# Unable to connect with MySQLConnection to remote database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Connection made from MySQL Workbench and Visual Studio Server Explorer works just fine. But when I try to use it in code trough MySQL connection
 with the same connection string as Server Explorer it gives me an Error.

> "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions {MyDatabaseIP}:3306"

I have tried multiple connection strings, and tried MySql connector from NuGet (many versions) and installing manually. Also tried disabling firewall and looked for answer through web.

```
     string myConnectionString;

        myConnectionString = "server=MyDatabaseIP;user id=admin;pwd=mYPasSword;database=MyBase;persistsecurityinfo=True";


        using (var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
```

I've got the error message on conn.Open();

Below my working server explorer configuration.

[image: Working configuration of Server Explorer]

server=MyDatabaseIP;user id=admin;database=MyBaser;persistsecurityinfo=True

[EDIT]
I've been to able to somehow closely determine what is causing the problem. I have tried different machines and problem persists on windows 10 ones, my program and test script are working fine on all windows 7 and 8 machines. I have also tried connectivity from python script and it works!(Even on windows 10) But when I made an exe from py file it still cannot connect to server. The same issue.

Comment: Are you sure? despite the squiggled out area the bit with id=(username); pwd=(password) isnt long in the squiggle.. and actually looks to be missing the password perhaps. as per the string at the bottom.  Suggesting a different userID and password

Comment: I have double checked everything. I have managed to check it and indeed connectivity works on windows 7 machines with the same files. But not on windows 10.

Comment: What happens if you “run as administrator”

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way,

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);

Or try to include these,

using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Comment: I have tried both of these as suggested. None have worked unfortunately. The error message is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding port in connection string and the make the connection -

```
 var ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;user id=test;password=test@123;persistsecurityinfo=True;port=3306;database=mydb;SslMode=none;"

 using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(DatabaseServiceUrl))
 {
        con.Open();
 }
```

Comment: I have tried your solution besides having to change "DatabaseServiceUrl' to "connectionString" it is still not working. Unfortunately.